# Giving custom variable to `hue` in sns.pairplot (Seaborn)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have the **air quality**([link here](https://app.quadstat.net/dataset/airquality)) dataset that contains missing values. I've imputed them while creating a dummy dataframe[using `df.isnull()`] to keep track of the missing values.

**My goal is to generate a pairplot using seaborn(or otherwise - if any other simpler method exists) that gives a different color for the imputed values.**

This is easily possible in matplotlib, where the parameter `c` of `plt.plot` can be assigned a list of values and the points are colored(but the problem is I can plot only against two columns and not a pairplot). A possible solution is to iteratively to create subplots against pairs of columns(which can make the code quite complicated!!)

However, in Seaborn (which already has the builtin function for pairplot) you are supposed to provide `hue='column-name'` which is not possible in this case as the missingness is stored in the dummy dataframe and need to retrieve the corresponding columns for color coding.

Please let me know how I can accomplish this in the simplest manner possible.

Comment: Create a new dataframe that will contain the column you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I ended up solving my problem. I'll probably post the same solution here. However, I achieved this through matplotlib.